# Why powershell workflow is so slower than usual function with same functionality?

Tags: performance, powershell, workflow

```
workflow test1{
parallel{
      1
      2
      Get-Process
      4
      5
      }
}
function test2{
      1
      2
      Get-Process
      4
      5         
}
```

When running `test1` and `test2`,`test1` is obviously slower than `test2`.And `measure-command` also proves this.

Why this happended?In what case does `workflow` should be used?

I work on Windows 7,PS 5.1.

Comment: Use runspace instead of workflows. You can use Jobs too.

Comment: Workflows are slower because they run with a different engine that does [additional things the regular PowerShell engine doesn't](http://www.informit.com/articles/article.aspx?p=2481897). If you don't know what you need workflows for: don't bother using them.